# Limit Access for Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName}) in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I am an administrator of an Azure DevOps Organization and have the following projects:

- InnerSource
- Foo
- Bar

I'd like the YAML pipelines of `Foo` and `Bar` to have read access to the private Git repositories in `InnerSource`. This I got working by disabling the "Limit job authorization scope to current project" option for my organization and the respective projects. To my understanding, this lets the pipelines run under the `Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})` identity instead of the `{ProjectName} Build Service ({OrgName})` identity.

Now I want to prevent pipelines in `Foo` from accessing `Bar` or vice versa. The info box on [Understand job access tokens - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope)
 reads like this isn't possible. However, there is also the section about "Managing build service account permissions", which reads differnt.

Also [Default permissions and access quick reference - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?view=azure-devops#git)
 states:

> By default, the Project Collection Build Service can read from all repositories. Any pipeline which runs within the project collection scope can potentially read any repository in the organization or collection. To remove this permission for a repository, change the Read permission to Deny for the Project Collection Build Service.

However, I do not find the `Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})` user in any security settings dialog. Also searching for it does not present me any results.
I tried to restrict permissions of `[{OrgName}]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts` but this does not seem to have any effect. The repository can still be read from pipelines of a different project.

Here is a screenshot of the Repository Security configuration of Project `Foo`. Pipelines from other projects running under the `Project Collection Build Service`still can access the repository, though:

[image]

Any clues what I am doing wrong here? Is this possible at all?

Comment: To summarize my question / use case: I'd like pipelines from projects `foo` and `bar` to access `InnerSource` while - at the same time - prevent `foo` from accessing accessing `bar` or vice versa. 
So far, I only have figured out to configure the both extremes: Limit access to the current project or open access to all resources within the organization...

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Read` access to `Project Collection Build Service` if you just want to have read only access yto the repos.At the moment you have `Deny`.

Please try this setting on project level:

[image]

Comment: This is what I want. The screenshot is from Project "Foo". I don't want the Project Collection Build Service to access the Repository of "Foo". But it is still possible despite the "Deny".

Comment: Currently you selected AllRepositories. You could do the same at repo level. Please just select the repo and you will get the same settings but for single repo. Is this what you want?

Comment: On repo level, the permissions are inherited. So it is also set to "Deny"

Comment: @Schwarzzz I'm not sure if to helps. But can check my edit and give a try?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `[{OrgName}]\Project Collection Build Service Accounts` is the wrong scope. There is in fact a `User` with the name `Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})` which can be added to the security settings.

The tricky part for me: I did not get any auto-completion help on this in the portal. I had to type in almost the full name, before it showed up in the list.

Looks like my use case cannot be implemented, though.
The `Read` permission for repositories is a system permission, which cannot be overwritten...

[image]